# Array not following curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'am trying to model a tank wheelchair, I have made a curve for tank treads but when I make array of cubes it is not following the curve. What should I do so that my cubes not only follow the curve but also I could be able to move the cubes along curve to simulate tank tracks?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cube must have the same position as the curve (select the curve, hit Shift+S and Place 3D cursor to curve's origin, then select the cube and again Shift+S to move Selection to 3D cursor).
Also, you must apply transformations on the cube so it can properly fit the curve (Ctrl+A).
I have updated and attached your file so you can look at it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jan , How did you make this video like tutorial ? Is it a gif ?

Comment: I am glad I could help :) It is a gif and I use this free recorder which is simple and works flawlessly. I record at 10fps. I have updated the "tutorial" so you can see also the key combinations (Screencast Keys Blender addon).
https://screentogif.codeplex.com/